# find an element of an array in another array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays of ints, "a" and "b". I want to find if a[0],a[1], etc, are inside b[] too. I have tried this:

```
int emfanisi(int a[], int b[], int x){
   int i, j;
   for(i=0; i<x; i++)
   {
       for(j=0; j<x; j++)
       {
            if(a[i] = b[j])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
       }
   }
}
```

In main I do this:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
   pos = 0;
   pos = emfanisi(a,b,2);
   if(pos = 1)
      printf("The %d number shows in the second array\n", i+1);
   else
      printf("The %d number doesnt show in the second array\n", i+1);
}
```

But this does not seem to work!

Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *assignment*:

```
if(a[i] = b[j])
```

use `==` for equality check. Note marking the arguments as `const` would have produce a compiler error:

```
int emfanisi(const int a[], const int b[], const int x){
```

Similar mistake later also:

```
if (pos = 1) /* Should be == */
```

Note you can eliminate `pos`:

```
if(emfanisi(a,b,2))
```

And as [tafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22186/tafa) has pointed out don't exit when elements do not equal, only when they equal.

---

To determine if *all* elements of `a` are contained in `b` then you need to keep a count of the matches (`i` would be suitable if you `break` when an element of `a` is not found) found and return `1` if the number of matches found equals the number of elements in `a` and return `0` otherwise.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: @dothedos, updated as similar problem with `pos`.

Answer (score 3):

```
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

This makes emfanisi function to return 0 immediately if the first elements of a and b are not equal. Instead put that return statement after the completion of the for loops.

```
int emfanisi(int a[], int b[], int x){

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<x; j++)
        {
                if(a[i] == b[j])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```